# Como popular objeto ReportDataSource() em um formulário webform.aspx?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, webforms, reportviewer

Como exemplo abaixo segue o exemplo da Entidade, Interface, Repositorio e o Controller do sistema MVC.
Na sequencia o codigo de um `formulário webform.aspx` que uso para exibir o `Pedido usando o ReportViewer`, o problema é que quando tento exibir o pedido sempre retorna `Null`. 
Ao debugar o sistema nem chega no `Repositorio`, a impressão que tenho é que do jeito que estou fazendo funciona quando é um Controller e falha quando é um WebForm.

Com essa estrutura de Entidade, Interface e Repositorio como faço para popular o objeto `ReportDataSource()` em um formulário WebForm ?

**ENTIDADE PEDIDO:**

```
public class Pedido
    {
        [Key]
        public int PedidoID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataPedido { get; set; }
    }
```

**INTERFACE:**

```
public interface IPedido: IDisposable
    {
        Pedido ObterPedidoPorID(int pPedidoID);
    }
```

**REPOSITORIO:**

```
public class PedidoRepositorio: IPedido
    {
        private readonly ctx _repositorio = new ctx();
        private bool disposed = false;

        public Pedido ObterPedidoPorID(int pPedidoID)
        {

                return _repositorio.Pedidos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.PedidoID == pPedidoID);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _repositorio.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public class PedidoController : Controller
    {
        private IPedido _IRepositorio;

        public PedidoController()
            : this(new PedidoRepositorio())
        { }

        public PedidoController(IPedido repositorio)
        {
            _IRepositorio = repositorio;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Editar(int pPedidoID)
        {
            try
            {
                Pedido _pedido = _IRepositorio.ObterPedidoPorID(pPedidoID);
                return View(_pedido);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(new Pedido());
            }
        }
    }
```

**RELATÓRIO - Pedido.aspx**

```
public partial class Pedido : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public IPedido _IRepositorio;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                int _PedidoID = 4;
                var _pedido = _IRepositorio.ObterPedidoPorID(_PedidoID);

                var reportDS = new ReportDataSource();
                reportDS.Name = "dsPedido";
                reportDS.Value = _pedido;

                rptPedido.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDS);
                rptPedido.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Areas/Administrativo/Reports/Pedido.rdlc";
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `_IRepositorio` não está sendo atribuido a instância???

Comment: Assim `IPedido _IRepositorio = new IPedido();` dá erro: _não pode ser instânciada classe abstrata ou uma interface_  e assim `PedidoRepositorio _IRepositorio = new PedidoRepositorio(); , funciona porém eu não queria acessar a classe de repositorio diretamente, já que tenho uma interface para isso.

Comment: tem alguma coisa errado no seu código...

Comment: Como está resolvendo a injeção de dependência?
Você precisa usar o simpleInjector ou Ninject para isso ...
Com um destes frameworks configurado vc poderá indicar que seu IPedido será resolvido com a implementação Pedido()

Comment: @Virgilio Novic sim, provavelmente existe algo errado e não sei qual, por enquanto estou criando a instância desse jeito mesmo.

Comment: @Lucas Lopes desconheço esses frameworks `simpleInjector ou Ninject`